# Increment Counter Returning 'null' in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am making this function and model that needs to return a particular String + an increment counter to string. Here is how it looks:

**function screen**

function to increment:

```
add(number) {
    number++;
}

addItem(String item) {
     //returns null not sure why
     item = item + " " + add(1).toString();
     _cartItems.add(item);
     notifyListeners();
}
```

**another screen that uses that function**

```
 onPressed: () =>
                                                  
       model.addItem(
        "${name.name}")
```

What I would like to be returned from onPressed would be:

```
Name 1
Name 2
```

and so on on each press it would just increment the number to one more. However now it is returning null. I have also tried to make the function with setState, but it is also returning null. Is there a reason why it is so? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not return anything in your addItem method. That is why it is null. You can try to return that item like this:

```
 String addItem(String item) {
   item = item + " " + add(1).toString();
   _cartItems.add(item);
   notifyListeners();
   return item; // Here is important!
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Your functions currently don't `return` any values.

Try:

```
int add(int number) {
 number++;
 return number;
}

String addItem(String item) {
//returns null not sure why
item = item + " " + add(1).toString();
_cartItems.add(item);
notifyListeners();
return item;
}
```

If you don't want to return anything in the addItem method and just want to add the generated number to _cartItems, you can also leave out `return item;` and keep the method as it is.

Comment: Oh right, I've been working all day and kinda am blind. Thank you guys!

Answer (score 1):

You forget the return keyword..